# Picture on NFC tags

Tags: java, android, tags, nfc, ndef

With the latest NFC tags, it is possible to store up to 8k of data.
So I would like to know how to store a picture on a tag, like the NXP TagWriter app.

I found no information about it. Can anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MIME type records to store images on NFC tags. If, for instance, your image is a JPEG image, you would use the MIME type "image/jpeg". You NDEF record could then look like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
+ MB=1, ME=1, CF=0, SR=0, IL=0, TNF=MIME +
+----------------------------------------+
+ Type Length = 10                       +
+----------------------------------------+
+ Payload Length = N                     +
+----------------------------------------+
+ image/jpeg                             +
+----------------------------------------+
+ <Your image data (N bytes)>            +
+----------------------------------------+
```

On Android, you could create such a record using

```
byte[] myImage = ...;
NdefRecord myImageRecord = NdefRecord.createMime("image/jpeg", myImage);
```

Or using the constructor of `NdefRecord`:

```
byte[] myImage = ...;
NdefRecord myImageRecord = new NdefRecord(
        NdefRecord.TNF_MIME_MEDIA,
        "image/jpeg".getBytes("US-ASCII"),
        null,
        myImage
);
```

Once you have a `Tag` handle of an NDEF tag (i.e. through receiving and NFC discovery intent), you could then write the NDEF record to the tag:

```
NdefMessage ndefMsg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { myImageRecord });

Tag tag = ...;
Ndef ndefTag = Ndef.get(tag);
if (ndefTag != null) {
    ndefTag.connect();
    ndefTag.writeNdefMessage(ndefMsg);
    ndefTag.close();
} else {
    NdefFormatable ndefFormatable = NdefFormatable.get(tag);
    if (ndefFormatable != null) {
        ndefFormatable.connect();
        ndefFormatable.format(ndefMsg);
        ndefFormatable.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, it works like a charm. Didn't know this way of recording. I search a better way than convert to string. You gave it :-) Thanks so much

Comment: @  Michael Roland : Done :-)

Comment: @All : Once saved on the nfc, I need to read it. I can read texts but now Images. Anyone knows ? (I used the ndefRecord)

Comment: @StéphaneGROSSMANN In theory, Android's default Tags app should handle images if there is *no other* app registered for an image/* MIME type (or whatever the first record in your NDEF message is). THough I have never tested if Android actually displays the image in the Tags app. Other than that, you would need to create your own image viewer app that (optionally) registers for the image/jpeg MIME type and then loads the record's payload into e.g. an ImageView widget.

Comment: Thanks, I got it with : see below
@All : With this post :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945545/writting-an-image-using-ndefmessage