# Store image in Nfc tags

Tags: nfc, ndef

Is it possible to store and read an image from an nfc tag? I am not talking about the url of the image but the image as a whole. (smaller size ofcourse) I am working on a small project and it would be a great help if someone could provide me with this info

Comment: possible duplicate of [Picture on nfc tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590420/picture-on-nfc-tags)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store an image in a NDEF record. No need for any base64 encoding either. Due to the somewhat limited size of NFC tags you will be restricted to quite small images though.

To do so use the NDEF type "SmartPoster". It can contain an image tag (along with other mostly optional extra-data such as action-records and text-records).

You'll find all relevant information how to encode the data in the specification:

http://www.cardsys.dk/download/NFC_Docs/NFC%20Smart%20Poster%20Record%20Type%20Definition%20Technical%20Specification.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could base64-encode the image, and store the resulting string. You are going to nave to use a very small image or a very large (expensive) NFC tag, though.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64